# scoreText.text not working in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

"Score:" is not being displayed on unity ide.i have tried a lot and nothing seems to be working and not getting output as expected.Thankyou.Sorry for bad English.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class uiManager : MonoBehaviour {
public Text scoreText;
int score;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    score = 0;

}
void score_view()
{
    score = move.score;
    Debug.Log("uiManager Score:"+score);
    scoreText.text = "Score:"+score;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    score_view();

}
}
```

Comment: `Update` only runs when the game is running. You will not see that if you are not running the game

Answer (score 0):

Update is called once per frame, if your GameObject is active, and your script is Enabled.
Moreover, your game should be running.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html

You can check this states with these variables:

```
this.gameObject.activeSelf
this.enabled
```